# Emoticons - CSS backgrounds or inline images?

Tags: html, regex

I was thinking to replace user text like `:)`, `:P` in comments with smilies (emoticons). Using regex. Do you think it's a good idea for the replacement to be a span element with a class? Then I apply the smiley image to that class?

Or should I just replace that text with `<img>` tags?

CSS is usually seen as not part of the content, but these image smileys are...
(if you disable the css, the text could change its meaning because emoticons are missing)

Comment: What do you mean by replace `:)` with an emoticon? It _is_ an [emoticon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon).

Comment: @Darknight I call the image version "smileys", the text version "emoticons"

Answer (score 1):

An emoticon is visual information presented using characters, so if you replace, say, “:-)” by something, the natural candidates are special characters such as “☺” (U+263A WHITE SMILING FACE) and an `img` tag like `<img alt=":-)" src="smiley.png">`.

Using an element with a background image has several drawbacks, including lack of any counterpart to the `alt` attribute and the common browser behavior of suppressing background images on printing.

It is somewhat risky to programmatically change anything emoticon-looking to e.g. an image. You cannot be sure that every “:-)” is an emoticon. All kinds of odd character combinations may arise in special fields. Besides, if the user was writing e.g. *about* emoticons, part of the content might get lost or distorted in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of smileys you are better of using the css sprite trick because it means the browser only has to download one image file instead of downloading a dozen smaller ones

this will result in less overhead and better caching

Comment: @FlorianMargaine lots of smaller images are less likely to be cached than one big image

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I incorrectly read your answer (which is why I deleted the comment).

Answer (score 0):

Have the smileys in plain-text, and display a picture instead with CSS.

You can achieve that by using a `<span>` or another element.

For instance, `:)` should be `<span class="normalsmiley">:)</span>` in the code.

Then the text will make sense for people not seeing images or with CSS disabled (they will see a text smiley).

Comment: But then if CSS is enabled and images are disabled (or just not seen), the emoticon is lost. And I suppose the implied assumption is that the emoticon is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to display the pictures. The best practice is to strip unwanted characters, invisible characters and HTML tags from user input, to avoid HTML code injection and cross-site scripting.